# Cocoa API - Does it contain a diff api?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, api, macos, diff

I'm wondering if there is a diff API in Cocoa, I've attempted to google it but its not bring back any results that are useful.

If there isn't an API for this would it be better to call `diff` from /usr/bin/ or to write my own diff.

All I need it for is text-files with a possibility of branching out into binaries and folders later.

Thanks

James

Comment: I'd still like to see the answer to this question, as I'm trying to use this feature in Cocoa Touch and AFAIK there is no way of accessing shell commands in App Store apps... any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally just use `diff` itself. All the command line tools are accessible via NSTask and NSPipe. It's trivial to write a wrapper class that manages it all for you.

Comment: I thought this might be the answer, I just hoped that there would be a nice API for it!

Comment: "It's trivial to write a wrapper class that manages it all for you." [ citation needed ]  ;-)

Comment: You can't use NSTask with iOS apps.

Answer (score 5):

Since this question was answered, it appears that something has come out:[Diff Match and Patch libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/)

I haven't tried it (yet) but it's what came up when I was looking for a diff library. There is an Obj-C port.

Comment: The Obj-C port is here: https://github.com/JanX2/google-diff-match-patch-Objective-C

Comment: This is a fork of the Obj-C port from inquisitiveSoft that has been refactored to use ARC. It looks a lot saner than the > 2 yrs old version: https://github.com/inquisitiveSoft/DiffMatchPatch-ObjC

Answer (score 0):

We recently remade an old project which applies a patch on your iOS device.. 
We used it to create diff files from a pc, make the iOS client download the patch and apply it.
It is called PatchPatch and it can be found here

https://bitbucket.org/Jkok/patchpatch

Try it out and let me know if it works for you.